# Ruby on rails, Is it possible to add categories to tags using gem acts as taggable on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to use fixed list of tags for each model (column_name = model_name).
I also need ability to create/update/delete all tags by category.
So, is it possible with acts_as_taggable?
Or better way is write everything without this gem?